# How to exit from nested Fortran loops?

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to write a program (in Fortran 95) that finds the **minimal** decomposition of  natural numbers up to N into a sum of at most 4 positive integers.

I've been trying to add and remove statements for a while to make it stop at only the minimal decomposition but I'm not getting anywhere. How do I make the program stop as soon as it's found the minimal decomposition?

```
PROGRAM SummeQuadrat
IMPLICIT NONE
 real:: start,finish
 integer:: a,b,c,d,g,x,y

 write(*,*) "Max n"
 read (*,*) y
 call cpu_time(start)

do x=1,y,1

  do a=0,x,1
   do b=a,x-a,1
    do c=b,x-b,1 
     do d=c,x-c,1
      if (a**2+b**2+c**2+d**2 .eq. x) then 
      write(*,*) "x=",x,d,c,b,a

      end if
     end do 

    end do
   end do
  end do
end do
call cpu_time(finish)
    write(*,*)finish-start
 end program SummeQuadrat
```

Comment: Welcome, be sure to take the [tour]. . Are you asking how to stop a Fortran program? `STOP` is used for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462371/how-to-stop-a-fortran-program-abnormally https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31873986/how-to-stop-a-subroutine-and-raise-a-flag Or are you asking how to recognize the minimum?

Comment: STOP stops everything. I want to know how I can have the program only give me the minimal decomposition, so a square will only give me itself instead of other possible sums of squares. Ex 4 giving me only 2 0 0 0 and not also 1 1 1 1.

Comment: Well you can always `exit` the loop instead of the `stop`, that is not the issue. So are you able to recognize you have the minimum?

Comment: I tried exiting after `d*d .eq. x' but it messes it up. Also in each other loop.

Comment: do you have any ideas?

Comment: Well, I do not understand what you are asking. Are asking how to recognize a minimum? Or how to exit a loop? I do not understand your question. Also, what is *"messes it up"*?

Comment: How would I implement a break after the minimum?

Comment: So you know when you are in the minimum?

Comment: It depends on the current integer, if I only need d then break, else find c etc.

Comment: I still do not undestand. Will just saying that `exit label` exits a loop with label `label` suffice to you? The loop with the label can be the outermost one or any other. Or you need a help with the ifs?

Comment: I will try with labels; thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I explained in the comments, I am not sure you are asking only how to break out of the loops or for more.

You can jump out of any loop using the `EXIT` statement. To exit from a loop which is not the innermost loop you are currently in you use a labeled loop and use the label in the `EXIT` statement to exit that particular loop.

```
outer: do x = 1, y

  do a = 0, x
   do b = a, x-a
    do c = b, x-b
     do d = c, x-c
      if (a**2+b**2+c**2+d**2 == x) then 
        write(*,*) "x=",x,d,c,b,a
        if (minimal(a,b,c,d)) exit outer
      end if
     end do 

    end do
   end do
  end do
end do outer
```

Comment: I labeled the first loop after the outer one and exited at it, works great thanks.

Comment: BTW, we normally do not put the `,1` step into every loop and we strongly prefer `==` and `/=` over `.eq.` and `.neq.` for readability.

Comment: I'd appreciate a cleaner version. This one is also extremely slow.

Comment: That's why I was asking many times and I was stressing I am not sure what you are up to! When you accepted the answer I assumed you are sattisfied and edited the question accordingly. So please describe exactly how you are determining the minimum and if you need help with that.

Comment: I'm just telling it to exit as soon as it finds a solution, it will be using the smallest `d` and then smallest `c`etc.

Comment: Is it possible to make the write function only give out the non zero numbers?

Comment: A couple of notes: If you have a do-construct with a do-construct-name, the end-do has to specify that name. Also the first positive result is minimal so no IF is required. However, I think you want to cycle outer to process the next x. The O.P. wanted the write statement to only print nonzero numbers, so I would change the contents of the block IF to (Sorry, I don't know how to format this) $$\begin{align}&\text{        write(*,'(i0," = ",i0"**2":3(" + ",i0,"**2":))') x, &}\\ &\text{           reshape([d,c,b,a],[count([d,c,b,a]/=0)])}\\ &\text{        cycle outer}\end{align}$$

Comment: I can't decypher this. With the first point you are right, the name is missing at the `end do`. I did not really dig inside the O.P.'s code, because it wasn't that clear what he wants (I asked several times, how is the minimum recognized! No real answer...). I will not pursue that now. You are free to explain everything in your answer.

Comment: Yeah, it seems you are only allowed one line of code so my suggestion would be to replace the contents of the block IF with `write(*,'(i0," = ",i0"**2":3(" + ",i0,"**2":))') x,reshape([d,c,b,a],[count([d,c,b,a]/=0)]);cycle outer` and that should satisfy the O.P.'s requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but it's kind of a fun problem so I thought I might post my own interpretation.

First off, if we cheat a little and peek at [the solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem) it can be seen that all 4 squares are only needed when x=4**k*(8*m+7). Thus we can search cheaply for 1 or 2 square solutions and on failure decide by the above criterion whether to search for a 3- or 4-square solution.

Then when we structure our loops, count down from the largest a such that a**2 <= x, then the largest b <= a such that a**2+b**2 <= x and so on. This takes the problem from O(x**4) down to O(x**1.5) so it can go much quicker.

For output format, by judicious use of the colon format we can write a single format that prints out results in perhaps a more readable fashion.

```
! squares.f90 -- Prints out minimal decomposition x into squares
!                for 1 <= x <= y (user input)
program squares
   use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV, only: REAL64
   implicit none
! Need this constant so we can take the square root of an
! integer.
   real(REAL64), parameter :: half = 0.5_REAL64
   real start, finish
   integer a,b,c
   integer amax,bmax,cmax,dmax
   integer amin,bmin,cmin
   integer x,y
! Format for printing out decomposition into squares
   character(40) :: fmt = '(i0," = ",i0"**2":3(" + ",i0,"**2":))'
   integer nzero

! Get uper bound from user
   write(*,'(a)',advance='no') 'Please enter the max N:> '
   read(*,*) y
   call cpu_time(start)
! Loop over requested range
   outer: do x = 1, y
      amax = sqrt(x+half)
! Check for perfect square
      if(amax**2 == x) then
         write(*,fmt) x,amax
         cycle outer
      end if
! Check for sum of 2 squares
      amin = sqrt(x/2+half)
      try2: do a = amax, amin, -1
         bmax = sqrt(x-a**2+half)
         if(bmax > a) exit try2
         if(a**2+bmax**2 == x) then
            write(*,fmt) x,a,bmax
            cycle outer
         end if
      end do try2
! If trailz(x) is even, then x = 4**k*z, where z is odd
! If further z = 8*m+7, then 4 squares are required, otherwise
! only 3 should suffice.
      nzero = trailz(x)
      if(iand(nzero,1)==0 .AND. ibits(x,nzero,3)==7) then
         amin = sqrt(x/4+half)
         do a = amax, amin, -1
            bmax = sqrt(x-a**2+half)
            bmin = sqrt((x-a**2)/3+half)
            do b = min(bmax,a), bmin, -1
               cmax = sqrt(x-a**2-b**2+half)
               cmin = sqrt((x-a**2-b**2)/2+half)
               do c = min(cmax,b), cmin, -1
                  dmax = sqrt(x-a**2-b**2-c**2+half)
                  if(a**2+b**2+c**2+dmax**2 == x) then
                     write(*,fmt) x,a,b,c,dmax
                     cycle outer
                  end if
               end do
            end do
         end do
      else
         amin = sqrt(x/3+half)
         do a = amax, amin, -1
            bmax = sqrt(x-a**2+half)
            bmin = sqrt((x-a**2)/2+half)
            do b = min(bmax,a), bmin, -1
               cmax = sqrt(x-a**2-b**2+half)
               if(a**2+b**2+cmax**2 == x) then
                  write(*,fmt) x,a,b,cmax
                  cycle outer
               end if
            end do
         end do
      end if
! We should have a solution by now. If not, print out
! an error message and abort.
      write(*,'(*(g0))') 'Failure at x = ',x
      stop
   end do outer
   call cpu_time(finish)
   write(*,'(*(g0))') 'CPU time = ',finish-start
end program squares
```